# Getting (x,y) value over click mouse from JFreeChart

Tags: onclicklistener, jfreechart

I would like to catch click event over *JFreeChart* and show by console the *x* and *y* value of the nearest data, not just clicks within the boundary of a `ChartEntity`.

If it is not possible (*y* value is not exist for that *x* value), I would like to get the *x* value.

**EDIT:**

Marker shows so far to click. Click handler code:

```
Point2D po = chartPanel.translateScreenToJava2D(event.getTrigger().getPoint());
Rectangle2D plotArea = chartPanel.getScreenDataArea();
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
chartX = plot.getDomainAxis().java2DToValue(po.getX(), plotArea, plot.getDomainAxisEdge());
chartY = plot.getRangeAxis().java2DToValue(po.getY(), plotArea, plot.getRangeAxisEdge());
plot.removeDomainMarker(marker);
marker = new ValueMarker(chartX);
marker.setPaint(Color.red);
plot.addDomainMarker(marker);
System.out.println("X:" + chartX + ", Y:" + chartY);
```

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach based on this [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107935/230513).

Comment: @trashgod I dont want x,y coordinates but x,y values

Comment: As shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20107935/230513): Get the dataset from the `XYItemEntity`; get the values from the dataset.

Comment: @trashgod, thank you for your interest. The code you link only works when you clic on exact point. I need clic over any place and get the x value.

Comment: Did you try enabling the `chartMouseMoved()` handler?

Comment: @trashgod, what do you mean? I have implemented ChartMouseListener, so I have a chartMouseMoved method but it is empty. I only need get X value when I clic on the chart (chatMouseClicked method).

Comment: I've never done it this way; a [mcve] might make it easier for someone else to answer.

Comment: Reopened; possible duplicate of [*Dispay mouse coordinates near to mouse as hints (on mouse move)*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21172794/230513).