# Get currently displaying tooltip

Tags: java, swing, clipboard, jfreechart

Is there some way to copy the currently displayed tooltip to the clipboard as a string without complex XY-coord calculation that maps to the tooltip text area?  This is especially challenging on a chart with tooltip displayed at an angle, also to only capture if being displayed. For example to get <kbd>ctl-c</kbd> to copy the displaying tooltip to clipboard:

```
PlotThisDaysData extends JFrame implements ... KeyListener{

@Override
public void keyTyped( KeyEvent e ) {
    char typed = e.getKeyChar();
    if ( typed == KeyEvent.VK_C ) /*VK_C?*/ {

        String tooltipStr = myChart.???();  // <<<<<<<<<<<<< get displaying tooltip <<<<

        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection( tooltipStr );
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents( selection, selection );
    }
}
```

Perhaps there is some event when a tooltip gets displayed so I can store a String pointer and use when <kbd>ctl-c</kbd> is entered?

[image: example of a tooltip to capture]

Answer (score 2):

Tooltips are displayed in response to mouse events received by the chart's enclosing [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html). To copy the currently displayed tooltip to the clipboard as the mouse moves,

1. Add a `ChartMouseListener` to the chart panel, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107935/230513).
2. When your listener sees a desired `ChartEntity`, ask the `ChartPanel` for the relevant text and copy it to the clipboard.

   ```
   Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
   Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
   …
       @Override
       public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent cme) {
           …
           String t = chartPanel.getToolTipText(cme.getTrigger());
           clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(t), null);
       }
   ```

A similar approach can be used in a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20getMenuShortcutKeyMask). Use the chart panel's `getMousePosition()` to construct the required `MouseEvent` trigger.

1. Get the chart panel's `InputMap`, `ActionMap`, and the platform's shortcut mask.

   ```
   InputMap im = chartPanel.getInputMap();
   ActionMap am = chartPanel.getActionMap();
   int mask = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
   ```
2. Put the desired `KeyStroke` in the chart panel's `InputMap`

   ```
   im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, mask), "copytip");
   ```
3. Put the corresponding `Action` in the chart panel's `ActionMap`

   ```
   am.put("copytip", new AbstractAction() {
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           Point p = chartPanel.getMousePosition();
           String t = chartPanel.getToolTipText(new MouseEvent(chartPanel,
               0, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0, p.x, p.y, 0, false));
           clipboard.setContents(new StringSelection(t), null);
       }
   });
   ```

Avoid [`KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), as it *requires* keyboard focus.