# JFreeChart multiple tooltips along x-axis

Tags: java, tooltip, jfreechart

I have added tooltips into line chart using `StandardXYToolTipGenerator`.

```
final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
plot.setRenderer(renderer);
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator());
```

It works well, but I need to move cursor to the precise point to show the tooltip. I hope I can do something like [Plotly](https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/GJPjeY) where the tooltips of all series will be shown along the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`, you can enable tooltips by setting the `tooltips` parameter to `true`. Note how the factory's [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#line.1984) resembles your fragment.

Once enabled, it may help to let the renderer make the corresponding shapes visible:

```
final XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer r = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
r.setBaseShapesVisible(true);
```

In some cases, you may even want to enlarge the shapes:

```
r.setSeriesShape(0, ShapeUtilities.createTranslatedShape(
    new Rectangle(12, 12), -6, -6));
```

A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20107935/230513). Note that the `ChartMouseListener` can respond to an `AxisEntity`, too.

[image]

You can also selectively change the shape, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20359200/230513). You can access the displayed tooltip, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45766227/230513).

Comment: Actually what you mention did not answer my question. I want to implement something like https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/GJPjeY where the multiple tooltips will be show on the data point when mouse hover over. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: These are just some alternatives. You can display anything you want in your `ChartMouseListener` for a `ChartEntity` of type `AxisEntity`. I'd probably update an adjacent `TableModel`.